# auto_increment with the newly created column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL, I have a table called transaction_detail

the create table statement is

```
Create table transaction_detail(
tx_code varchar(25),
acct varchar(25),
ltx varchar(25),
crcy varchar(25));
```

I want to add a column called line_key with auto_increment by 1 in this.
I know a way to create another table similar to this and add a column with auto_increment in that and insert all data from this table to a newly created table, but I am looking for a easier way like altering this table and adding a column with incremented value.

Comment: you want to alter the table `transaction_detail` and add a column which increment value by 1 ?

Comment: yes something like     alter table transaction_detail add column like_key INT; this will add a new column with no values I want that column with values from 1 to the value of the last row in the table

Comment: @mb1987 see the question i linked. Mysql will auto generate the ids for you.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can insert from one table to another

```
INSERT database.tableNameNew SELECT * FROM database.tableNameOld;
```

This way you can copy table structure

```
CREATE TABLE database.tableNameNew LIKE database.tableNameOld;
```

This is your table with auto increament

```
Create table transaction_detail(
        `line_key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `tx_code` varchar(25),
        `acct` varchar(25),
        `ltx` varchar(25),
        `crcy` varchar(25)
        PRIMARY KEY (`line_key`),
    );
```

Comment: I know this way my friend

Comment: May b i got you wrong then @mb1987